# compatibility hbase and hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase, compatibility

Hadoop 2.2.0 and HBase 0.98.0-hadoop2 are compatible ?

EDIT: http://hbase.apache.org/book/configuration.html already read.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not compatible.
Read [this](https://github.com/hortonworks/hoya/releases) release.

Comment: Can you advise version hadoop and hbase which hadoop has version min 2.0.4?

Comment: or which hbase version is compatible with hadoop 2.2.0 ?

Comment: for any compatability check this:-  "http://hbase.apache.org/book/configuration.html"